# php scrape but no newline from html

Tags: php, mysql, newline, scrape, scraper

In html it would show the following:

```
<pre>
I am using stackoverflow
I like stackoverflow
Stackoverflow is cool!
</pre>
```

When I used php to scrape that content it would show the following in mysql db:

```
I am using stackoverflow I like stackoverflow Stackoverflow is cool!
```

it would display in one line and doesn't have any string /n or /r and would like to have it display the proper spacing/newline in mysql db. It would be great to know how to verify every step that the newlines are there and go from html to string and then from string to mysql.

Comment: how do you do the scraping? "It would be great to verify every step that the newlines are there and go from html to string and then from string to mysql." already sounds like a very good procedure to me to find the problem, how did that go?

Comment: By using simpleHtmlDom and curl through URL. Actually I would like to know how to go through those.

Answer (score 0):

the pre tag is doing all the alignment,spacing and new line addition. one solution is that you save the data in the db along with the pre tag opening and closing.
i have not checked it on my own. do tell me if it works or i'll think further

Comment: how do i save the pre tag opening and closing by the way? I seem to only grab the content that's inside the <pre>. And also would mysql db be able to make a new line if theres a pre tag opening and closing within the content?

Comment: actually i dont want to store the pre tag and i just need to make sure i get the html from the source and also keep the newlines since there're there but I just don't see them. So my question is how to store the newline string for those or even to make it display the content in mysql the same way as in the way html display in broswer.